# Jquery, can't connect to the web service - 404 error

Tags: jquery, web-services

I have a web service with the url:
http://www.m-hakehilot.co.il/kehila_search/kehilot/retrieve.json[^]

When I tested it in the SoapUI foftware, it seem to work well.
In the SoapUI I configured the service type to REST, and the method to POST.

After it, I tried to use it in ajax code, but I got the 404 (not found) error.
My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.m-hakehilot.co.il/kehila_search/kehilot/retrieve.json",
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log('get kehilot - error details:');
     console.log('XMLHttpRequest: ' + JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
     console.log('textStatus: ' + JSON.stringify(textStatus));
     console.log('errorThrown: ' + JSON.stringify(errorThrown));

     return [];
  },
  success: function (data) {
 //DO SOMETHING

  }
});
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you check the console you'll see this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.m-hakehilot.co.il/kehila_search/kehilot/retrieve.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.`. You need to enable CORS on your webservice.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the problem!

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you to accept

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console you'll see this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.m-hakehilot.co.il/kehila_search/kehilot/retrieve.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.. You need to enable CORS on your webservice. – Rory McCrossan Jul 20 at 11:20

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console you'll see this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.m-hakehilot.co.il/kehila_search/kehilot/retrieve.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access..

You need to enable CORS on your webservice.